# Running commands on remote server and saving the result to a string variable in a Python script

Tags: python, bash, pexpect

How can I run commands on the remote server to which I login to, using `pexpect` and store the result in the form of a string into a variable?

I made a connection to the server in the following way:

```
COMMAND_PROMPT = '[#$] '
TERMINAL_PROMPT = '(?i)terminal type\?'
TERMINAL_TYPE = 'vt100'
SSH_NEWKEY = '(?i)are you sure you want to continue connecting'

child = pexpect.spawn('ssh -l %s %s'%(loginuser, servername))
i = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, SSH_NEWKEY, COMMAND_PROMPT, '(?i)password'])

if i == 0: # Timeout
    print('ERROR! could not login with SSH. Here is what SSH said:')
    print(child.before, child.after)
    print(str(child))
    sys.exit (1)

if i == 1: # In this case SSH does not have the public key cached.
    child.sendline ('yes')
    child.expect ('(?i)password')

if i == 2:
    # If a public key was setup to automatically login
    pass

if i == 3:
    child.sendline(password)
    # Now we are either at the command prompt or
    # the login process is asking for our terminal type.
    i = child.expect ([COMMAND_PROMPT, TERMINAL_PROMPT])
    if i == 1:
        child.sendline (TERMINAL_TYPE)
        child.expect (COMMAND_PROMPT)
```

Now suppose I want to execute the following command on the server I logged in to and save the result to a string in my python script itself:

```
 ps -ef|grep process1
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You want `pidof process1` if you value your sanity.

Comment: What command should I use if I want to run  `pidof process1` **on the server that I logged into _in_ my script** and **not the server that currenty has my script**, and also store the result as a string

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you.

```
import subprocess
import sys

url="http://www.anyurlulike.any"
# Ports are handled in ~/.ssh/config since we use OpenSSH
COMMAND="uname -a"
ssh = subprocess.Popen(["ssh", "%s" % url, COMMAND],
                   shell=False,
                   stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                   stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

result = ssh.stdout.readlines()
if result == []:
error = ssh.stderr.readlines()
print >>sys.stderr, "ERROR: %s" % error
else:
print result
```

Comment: Subprocess:
It's the default Python library that runs commands.
You can make it run ssh and do whatever you need on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `read()` function, it will give you the entire output.

```
result = child.read()
```